# Back filling NAs for missing dates across subjects

Tags: r, date

I can't seem to figure this out and was hoping someone could help me out.

I have a data set that has a bunch of subjects who have been tested over several days. However, some subjects were tested on certain days and not others. I was wondering if there was a way to insert the missing days for the subjects, when they weren't tested, and just have it read "NA" for the variables of interest? This way the dates are represented for each subject.

Here is an example data set, where I have 4 testing days, 1/1/2016 - 1/4/2016. You can see that some subjects are missing dates during that time period.

```
Subject <- c("Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Pat", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Jeff", "Jeff", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Art", "Art", "Art", "Karl", "Karl", "Hal", "Hal", "Hal", "Hal")
variable.1 <- rnorm(n = Subject, mean = 10, sd = 5)
variable.2 <- rnorm(n = Subject, mean = 20, sd = 5)
Date <- c("1/1/2016", "1/2/2016", "1/3/2016", "1/4/2016","1/1/2016", "1/2/2016", "1/3/2016", "1/4/2016", "1/1/2016", "1/3/2016", "1/1/2016", "1/2/2016", "1/3/2016", "1/4/2016", "1/2/2016", "1/2/2016", "1/3/2016", "1/2/2016", "1/4/2016", "1/1/2016", "1/2/2016", "1/3/2016", "1/4/2016" )

d <- data.frame(Subject, Date, variable.1, variable.2)
d$Date <- as.Date(d$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")

d
```

```html
   Subject       Date variable.1 variable.2
1      Pat 2016-01-01   8.341378   22.51838
2      Pat 2016-01-02  13.654822   19.50904
3      Pat 2016-01-03  14.078425   28.36888
4      Pat 2016-01-04  10.023648   24.18750
5      Bob 2016-01-01  11.409657   30.06393
6      Bob 2016-01-02   6.169438   21.85819
7      Bob 2016-01-03  12.388085   14.60456
8      Bob 2016-01-04  15.311546   20.31606
9     Jeff 2016-01-01  16.502111   30.14965
10    Jeff 2016-01-03   9.941720   22.56740
11     Tom 2016-01-01   9.594301   24.72596
12     Tom 2016-01-02  17.798279   14.81699
13     Tom 2016-01-03   6.097222   24.92846
14     Tom 2016-01-04   8.434669   20.47638
15     Art 2016-01-02   1.687036   37.17307
16     Art 2016-01-02   5.855712   19.91173
17     Art 2016-01-03   8.295704   18.69689
18    Karl 2016-01-02   4.747927   21.72881
19    Karl 2016-01-04   0.676263   27.17804
20     Hal 2016-01-01   7.685603   23.51874
21     Hal 2016-01-02  16.965498   15.08288
22     Hal 2016-01-03   7.018053   20.09474
23     Hal 2016-01-04  11.111013   22.21986
```

Subject       Date variable.1 variable.2
1      Pat 2016-01-01   8.341378   22.51838
2      Pat 2016-01-02  13.654822   19.50904
3      Pat 2016-01-03  14.078425   28.36888
4      Pat 2016-01-04  10.023648   24.18750
5      Bob 2016-01-01  11.409657   30.06393
6      Bob 2016-01-02   6.169438   21.85819
7      Bob 2016-01-03  12.388085   14.60456
8      Bob 2016-01-04  15.311546   20.31606
9     Jeff 2016-01-01  16.502111   30.14965
10    Jeff 2016-01-03   9.941720   22.56740
11     Tom 2016-01-01   9.594301   24.72596
12     Tom 2016-01-02  17.798279   14.81699
13     Tom 2016-01-03   6.097222   24.92846
14     Tom 2016-01-04   8.434669   20.47638
15     Art 2016-01-02   1.687036   37.17307
16     Art 2016-01-02   5.855712   19.91173
17     Art 2016-01-03   8.295704   18.69689
18    Karl 2016-01-02   4.747927   21.72881
19    Karl 2016-01-04   0.676263   27.17804
20     Hal 2016-01-01   7.685603   23.51874
21     Hal 2016-01-02  16.965498   15.08288
22     Hal 2016-01-03   7.018053   20.09474
23     Hal 2016-01-04  11.111013   22.21986

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `expand.grid` to create the full combinations for "Subject" and "Date", then do the `left_join` with the original dataset.

```
library(dplyr)
expand.grid(Subject = unique(d$Subject), Date = unique(d$Date)) %>%
                 left_join(., d) %>%
                 arrange(Subject, Date)
#   Subject       Date  variable.1 variable.2
#1      Art 2016-01-01          NA         NA
#2      Art 2016-01-02  9.65145589   28.44836
#3      Art 2016-01-02 12.58161500   16.06862
#4      Art 2016-01-03  0.02990953   19.62926
#5      Art 2016-01-04          NA         NA
#6      Bob 2016-01-01  7.82691227   19.08990
#7      Bob 2016-01-02  8.88546512   27.16044
#8      Bob 2016-01-03 12.26231157   19.81463
#9      Bob 2016-01-04 12.60452244   20.30380
#10     Hal 2016-01-01  2.66644221   17.86939
#11     Hal 2016-01-02 11.45246295   23.04896
#12     Hal 2016-01-03  4.94271258   22.06501
#13     Hal 2016-01-04  0.92676435   11.43378
#14    Jeff 2016-01-01  9.19183973   22.99084
#15    Jeff 2016-01-02          NA         NA
#16    Jeff 2016-01-03 12.56990234   18.69434
#17    Jeff 2016-01-04          NA         NA
#18    Karl 2016-01-01          NA         NA
#19    Karl 2016-01-02  9.80615533   14.65699
#20    Karl 2016-01-03          NA         NA
#21    Karl 2016-01-04 11.04105033   16.88379
#22     Pat 2016-01-01  5.50443769   14.81744
#23     Pat 2016-01-02 15.96919707   15.67234
#24     Pat 2016-01-03  5.52737822   15.48899
#25     Pat 2016-01-04  5.70531242   25.04813
#26     Tom 2016-01-01  0.09573680   32.44053
#27     Tom 2016-01-02 14.82955222   21.76676
#28     Tom 2016-01-03 13.17820753   11.44786
#29     Tom 2016-01-04 15.23101038   26.10275
```

---

If we are using `tidyr`, then this becomes more compact

```
library(tidyr)
complete(d, Subject, Date)
```

Comment: I load the tidyr library but it tells me that it can't find the function complete?

One other question though, in my data set, I have a few columns that are specific descriptors of the subject. When using the dplyr code it just plugs an NA in those columns when adding a date. Is there a way to have those columns coded with the descriptor for that individual? It seems like that might get pretty messy and complex though.

Comment: @user3585829  I am using `tidyr_0.4.1.9000`  Here, in this case, we only used the Subject and Date to get the full combinations, so naturally all other columns will get filled up with NA.  One option would be to `paste` the columns with the Date or Subject while doing the expand.grid and then separate it afterwards.